# How do i compress/change my mobile version redirect codes?

Tags: javascript, android, html, iphone

How do i compress/change my mobile version redirect codes? Its making my website really slow and online compressors aren't working.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    if((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone')!=-1)||(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPod')!=-1)||(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad')!=-1)){document.location="http://mobile.gv.x10.mx/"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   -1!=navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Android")&&(document.location="http://mobile.hj.x10.mx/");
</script>
<script>
    if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {
   location.replace("http://mobile.hj.x10.mx/");
</script>
<script>
    if (screen.width <= 850) {
        document.location = "http://mobile.hj.x10.mx/";
    }
</script>
```

Anyone have a better version that works for all platforms?

Comment: Why don't use htacces? I think is faster and easier then processing this in JavaScript (but I can be wrong), if you can use htacces I will be glad to post an answer

Comment: so, how do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will redirect all mobile devices to one page:

```
# Redirect Mobile Devices
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mobile.onlythebestoftheweb.x10.mx/ [R=301,L]
```

Or you can send each mobile device to a different page:

```
# Redirect Mobile Devices
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*iPhone.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mobile.onlythebestoftheweb.x10.mx/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*BlackBerry.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mobile.onlythebestoftheweb.x10.mx/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Android.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mobile.onlythebestoftheweb.x10.mx/[R=301,L]
```